# Add New XML Element via LINQ when path is variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Having a little bit of an issue with using XElement/LINQ to add a new element, when the path is unknown, and am fairly new to LINQ as well. In C#, Winforms

Edit: The 'ID' values in the xml are actually GUID's, just trimmed down here for ease of reading.

For example, if I have the below xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Structure>
    <Nodes>
      <Node ID="1" Name="A" />
      <Node ID="2" Name="B" />
      <Node ID="3" Name="C" >
        <Nodes>
          <Node ID="4" Name="D" />
          <Node ID="5" Name="E" >
            <Nodes>
              <Node ID="6" Name="F" />
            </Nodes>
          </Node>
        </Nodes>
      </Node>
    </Nodes>
  </Structure>
</Root>
```

Then my code snippet for inserting a new node (ID = 7 Name = G)  underneath Node 2 / B  is: 
(Note: I am previously identifying the target, in this case 2, hardcoded for brevity)

```
// Add Node:
_XML_Modify.Element("Structure")
.Elements("Nodes")
.Elements("Node")
.Where(item => item.Attribute("ID").Value == 2).FirstOrDefault()
.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Node",
new XAttribute("ID", 7),
new XAttribute("Name", "G")
));
```

But how can I add a new node, if I am not sure of the target? If for example to add the new node underneath node 4/D or 6/F where the path is different then the above.

Is it best to use recursion to find my target node in this scenario? I've tried that and struggled a little bit, but am thinking of doing a "Find", then if it has child nodes, call recursively until the target node is found.

Comment: Does your `ID` property have unique values?

Comment: Yes. The 'ID' values in the xml are actually GUID's, just trimmed down for ease of reading.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you can use `Descendants()` to find a node without knowing the exact path of the node. For example, to add the new node after node with `ID=6` :

```
_XML_Modify.Descendants("Node")
           .FirstOrDefault(o => (int)o.Attribute("ID") == 6)
           .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("Node",
                            new XAttribute("ID", 7),
                            new XAttribute("Name", "G")
                            ));
```

Note that this approach may be slower compared to using more specific path, especially given large XML document, because `Descendants()` will attempt to find matched node(s) within all branches.

Comment: Thank you, this works great based on tests on a small xml file.

Will see what performance is like when trying to manipulate a lot larger file.

And then of course the next step is to remove them as well.